# Using ForcebindIp

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet

Hi guys i want to use forcebindip.exe to my Context menu(right click menu) for windows 7  with the parameterse like given below

> Forcebindoip.exe -i 192.168.1.1

But when ever i add it to regedit fir with the below argument it wont work

> "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ForceBindIP.exe -i 192.168.1.109" "%1"

kindly help me on this

Comment: What exactly did you add to the registry? How does it not work, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the quotes in the wrong place. Try this:

```
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ForceBindIP.exe" -i 192.168.1.109 "%1"
```

Also judging by the fact your ForceBindIP is in the system folder, you may have an old version - the latest version runs from the Program Files folder. You can update it from https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip